# Retrieve data from indexedDB and return value to function calling

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I have share variable between javascript function which is asynchronous. One of them is main thread and another is event based. I want to return value when event is completed.

This is the code:

```
completeExecution = false;    // Shared Variable (Global Variable)
indexDBdata = {};             // Shared Variable (Global Variable)

function getPermission(key) {
    var permission_data={};

    if(exist_in_local) {
       indexdbConnection.getRecordByKey('userPermission',permitKey,function(data){
        indexDBdata=data; // Before its complete function return value
    });
    } else {
       // make ajax call & its working fine
    }
    return permission_data;
}
```

//get Data from IndexedDB

```
getRecordByKey:function(tableName,key,readRecords){
    if(isEmptyOrNull(readRecords)){
        console.log("callback function should not be empty");
        return;
    }

    if(isEmptyOrNull(tableName)){
        console.log("table name should not be empty");
        return;
    }

    var returnObj={};
    var isSuccessfull=false;

    if(this.dbObject.objectStoreNames.contains(tableName)){
        var transaction=this.dbObject.transaction(tableName);
        var objectStore = transaction.objectStore(tableName);
        objectStore.get(key).onsuccess = function(event) {
            returnObj=event.target.result;
        };

        **//Return object after this events compelte**
        transaction.oncomplete = function(evt) { 
            completeExecution=true;
            indexDBdata=returnObj;
            readRecords(returnObj);

        };

        transaction.onerror = function(evt) {
            completeExecution=true;
            indexDBdata={status:'404'};
            readRecords("Table Not found");
        };
    } else {
        completeExecution=true;
        indexDBdata={status:'404'};
        readRecords("Table Not found");
    }

}
```

**Problem** is while retrieving data from indexedDB it always returns `{}` (empty object). I want to synchronised event thread and main thread or wait for event to be completed. I don't want to directly manipulate DOM on callbacks I have to return value.

If you have solution to above problem or any other trick then please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `between javascript threads`... what do you mean? JavaScript is not multi-threaded.

Answer (score 1):

I don't find the question very clear, but if I understand it, then you need to learn more about writing asynchronous javascript. In general, functions that call callback functions are void (they return an undefined value). If you want to use the results of two callback functions together, then you will want to chain them so that upon the completion of the first function, which calls its callback function, the callback function then calls the second function which then calls the second callback. So there are four function calls involved. You will want to place the processing logic within the context of the successive callback function, instead of continuing the logic outside of the function and trying to use its return value.

In other words, instead of trying to do this:

```
function a() {}
function b() {}
var aresult = a();
var bresult = b(aresult);
// processing of both a and b
```

You would want to try and do something like following:

```
function a(acallback) {
  acallback(...);
}
function b(bcallback) {
  bcallback(...);
}

a(function(...) {
  b(function(...) {
    // all processing of both a and b
  });
});
```

Comment: Josh Beam I don't understand you, can you give me a very simple example, please?!